# Token for kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to login kubernetes dashboard with this [article](https://paradisetechsoftsolutions7.medium.com/how-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard-token-74891365334)

```
$kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
$kubectl proxy
```

I successfully started the dashboard server, however I try to make token.

```
$kubectl create service account dashboard -n default
```

It shows error like this `error: unknown command "account dashboard"`

There is mention to authentication in official [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serviceAccount` is one word, like so:

```
$ kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard -n default
serviceaccount/dashboard created
```

Small post note: the dashboard isn't really recommended to be ran in prod anymore and for local minikube environments you can now run the following to bring the dashboard up:

```
minikube dashboard
```